# Action method not working in p:menuitem

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Action method is not working in my `<p:menuitem>`. I would like to change `activeIndex` via an action method of `<p:menuitem>`.

The code below is the code on template page that is used in my pages:

```
<h:form>
    <p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{loginBean.activeindex}">  
        <p:menuitem value="Home" url="Menu.jsf" icon="ui-icon-star" />
        <p:menuitem value="Fabricants" url="/pagess/pagesFabricant/Fabricant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-wrench"   action="#{loginBean.Dirige(1)}" /> 
        <p:menuitem value="Composants" url="/pagess/pagesComposant/Composant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-search"  action="#{loginBean.Dirige(2)}"/> 
        <p:menuitem value="Dossier d'equivalence" url="DEQ.jsf" icon="ui-icon-document" action="#{loginBean.Dirige(3)}"/> 
    </p:tabMenu> 
</h:form>
```

This is my bean:

```
public class LoginBean {

    private int activeindex;

    public int getActiveindex() {
    return activeindex;
    }

    public void setActiveindex(int activeindex) {
        this.activeindex = activeindex;
    }  

   public void Dirige(int a){
       setActiveindex(a);
   }
}
```

When I click on any menu item the action method is not called. I did some debugging to ensure that the method is not called. Alternatively, the method is working with `<p:commandButton>`.

---

This is the template

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
<ui:insert name="title">Title</ui:insert></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

    <h:form>
    <p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{loginBean.activeindex}">  
        <p:menuitem value="Home" url="Menu.jsf" icon="ui-icon-star" />
        <p:menuitem value="Fabricants" url="/pagess/pagesFabricant/Fabricant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-wrench"   action="#{loginBean.Dirige(1)}" /> 
        <p:menuitem value="Composants" url="/pagess/pagesComposant/Composant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-search"  action="#{loginBean.Dirige(2)}"/> 
        <p:menuitem value="Dossier d'equivalence" url="DEQ.jsf" icon="ui-icon-document" action="#{loginBean.Dirige(3)}"/> 
    </p:tabMenu> 
    </h:form>
    <p/>
    <table border="5" align="center">
      <tr><th class="title">
        Bienvenue #{loginBean.username} dans Notre application Ipertool
      </th></tr>
    </table><p/>


    <ui:insert name="body">Body</ui:insert>

    <p:separator id="separator"/> 

    <ui:include src="/templates/includes/footer.xhtml"/>
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

This is page Fabricant when I press menuitem Fabricant

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="/templates/template.xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:define name="title">Liste Fabricants</ui:define>
<ui:define name="body">
<h:form id="form">  

    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>  

    <p:commandLink  value="Ajouter Fabricant" action="#{fabricantbean.Ajouter()}"><img src="/image/ajout.jpg" alt= "Ajouter"></img></p:commandLink> 

    <p:dataTable id="cars" var="fab" value="#{fabricantbean.list}" paginator="true" rows="10"  rowKey="#{fab.idFabricant}"
                 selection="#{fabricantbean.selectitem}" selectionMode="single" emptyMessage="Aucun Fabricants Trouve">  

        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{fabricantbean.onRowSelect}"   
                    update=":form:dialog :form:growl" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" />  

        <p:column  id="modelColumn" filterBy="#{fab.nomFabricant}"   
                headerText="Nom Fabricant" footerText="contains"  
                filterMatchMode="contains">  

            <h:outputText value="#{fab.nomFabricant}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                    Lien Site  
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{fab.lienSite}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                    Staut Fabricant  
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{fab.statutFabricant}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                    Nom Contact  
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{fab.nomContact}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                    Mail Contact  
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{fab.mailContact}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                    Action  
            </f:facet>  
            <p:commandButton value="Modifier" action="#{fabricantbean.Modifier()}"> 
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{fabricantbean.selectitem}" value="#{fab}" /> 
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton value="Supprimer" onclick="info.show()"  >
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{fabricantbean.selectitem}" value="#{fab}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>  
    </p:dataTable>
  <p:confirmDialog id="infodialoge"    message="Si vous supprimer ce Fabricant vous resquer de supprimer ces composant ainsi les DEQ"
                header="supprimer Fabricant" severity="alert" widgetVar="info">  

        <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Oui Sure"  oncomplete="info.hide()"  
                    action="#{fabricantbean.supprimer()}" update="form:cars"/>  
        <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Non " onclick="info.hide()" type="button" />   

    </p:confirmDialog>  

  <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Fabricant Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false"  dynamic="true" 
                showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">  

        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">  

            <f:facet name="header">  
                <p:graphicImage value="/images/cars/#{tableBean.selectedCar.manufacturer}.jpg"/>  
            </f:facet>  

            <h:outputText value="lien Reach:" />  
            <h:outputText value="#{fabricantbean.selectitem.lienReach}" />


            <h:outputText value="lien Fmd:" />  
            <h:outputText value="#{fabricantbean.selectitem.lienFmd}" />

            <h:outputText value="lien Rohs:" />  
            <h:outputText value="#{fabricantbean.selectitem.lienRohs}" />  

            <h:outputText value="lien cofc:" />  
            <h:outputText value="#{fabricantbean.selectitem.fichierCofc}" />  

            <h:outputText value="remarque:" />  
            <h:outputText value="#{fabricantbean.selectitem.remarqueFabricant}" />   

        </h:panelGrid>  

    </p:dialog> 
</h:form>  

</ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: can you post the code of your page where you click on the menu item and maybe the whole code pf your template?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the menu? Is it used for plain navigation, or to post some data, or just to update the index? By the way, you shouldn't post clarifications to your question as an answer, but should instead edit your question.

Comment: why don't you just edit your question instead of posting an answer?

Comment: Could it be, that it is doing url, but not action, because can do only one? As I understand action also can do redirect or forward. What if you put one action only without url?

Comment: Thank you, I'd like to use as navigation .. I would like to say to the user on what level it is .. I like to change the color (press) the item menu. All pages s but always returned the first index that is pressed

Comment: Ok .;so I should eleminate the url .and use the action methode to return the page and to change the active index .is that corect !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the problem is in fact the `url` in your `menuitem`.
You have to edit your `Dirige` method.
Try the following:

```
public String Dirige(int a){
   setActiveindex(a);
   if (a == 1) {
      return "/pagess/pagesFabricant/Fabricant.jsf";
   }else{
      if (a == 2) {
         return "/pagess/pagesComposant/Composant.jsf";
      }else{
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

and in your template you have to remove the url-Tags:

```
<h:form>
    <p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{loginBean.activeindex}">  
        <p:menuitem value="Home" url="Menu.jsf" icon="ui-icon-star" />
        <p:menuitem value="Fabricants" icon="ui-icon-wrench"   action="#{loginBean.Dirige(1)}" /> 
        <p:menuitem value="Composants" icon="ui-icon-search"  action="#{loginBean.Dirige(2)}"/> 
        <p:menuitem value="Dossier d'equivalence" icon="ui-icon-document" action="#{loginBean.Dirige(3)}"/> 
    </p:tabMenu> 
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thx very much for your cooperation ,I 'm doing that :) it works now

Comment: this answer served as a nice example for me to help with a completely unrelated problem. thanks.